# glmmTMB - Random effects on Zero-inflation component

Tags: mixed-model, zero-inflation, glmmtmb

I am planning to perform a zero-inflated negative binomial regression for colony forming units (CFUs) of bacteria with a drug treatment, accounting for variability in the intercept among experiments. I decided said approach, since there are some drugs in which I obtain a fair ammount of zeros. For that, I plan to use the `glmmTMB` package.

I was just wondering that, in order to model both the zero-inflated and the counts components of the model *with the random effect*, should I add the random effect on *both formulas*? e.g.

```
glmmTMB(CFU~Treatment+(1|Experiment),ziformula=~Treatment+(1|Experiment), family=nbinom2)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head if `glmmTMB` handles random effects in the `ziformula`. If it does, and you as the scientist think there's an appropriate theoretical justification for putting a random effect in the `ziformula`, then try it! Just keep in mind that it can be difficult to estimate multiple sets of random effects, and it may be difficult to actually get the model to fit when it's complex esp. if you have a small dataset. Keep an eye out for shenanigans and sense in the model results.

Comment: @AlexJ, can you please post this as an answer?  I answered the OP's question about whether `ziformula` can take a random effect [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2023q1/030345.html) (hint: it does, and it's right there in the documentation ...)

Comment: How many observations total, how many levels of the `Experiment` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does - see https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2023q1/030345.html (thanks [Ben](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/2126/ben-bolker)).

If you as the scientist think there's an appropriate theoretical justification for putting a random effect in the ziformula, then try it! Just keep in mind that it can be difficult to estimate multiple sets of random effects, and it may be difficult to actually get the model to fit when it's complex esp. if you have a small dataset. Keep an eye out for shenanigans and sense in the model results